# how to put uncommitted changes into master branch

Tags: git

In a project with a local Git repository a new branch called `alternate` was created from the `master` branch and changes were made to files in the working tree.  These changes have reached a point where they're ready to be pushed to the `master` branch.  The changes have not been committed yet on either `master` or `alternate`.  Is there a way to commit these changes directly to the `master` branch without having to commit them on `alternate` and then do a merge with `master`?  Note that this project does not have a remote Git repository.

Comment: checkout master and commit.  But why have you not already committed?  Commit early, commit often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume that alternate is still at the same revision of masterr?  If that is the case, just checkout master, it won't change anything in the working tree and then follow procedure to create a revision:

```
git checkout master
git add file1 file1
git commit -m 'new revision'
```

Comment: `alternate` and `master` originated from the same commit - verified this by running `git branch -v`.  Is that what's meant by "alternate is still at the same revision of master"?